# Foundation CLI error : return emojiWidthLookup.get( code ) ?? 2 ;

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation, yarnpkg, zurb-foundation-6

I'm a front end dev who's been using Zurb Foundation to build custom WordPress themes for years with no problems, but the last year, the CLI has been giving me nothing but grief. I've tried doing a full uninstall and reinstall of the Foundation CLI, Node, NPM, Yarn, Gulp, Bower, and whatever other component I keep getting asked for. Now, whenever I try and run a foundation command (even foundation -v), I get the following error.

```
robstephens@Local ~ % foundation -v
/Users/robstephens/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/string-kit/lib/unicode.js:237
        return emojiWidthLookup.get( code ) ?? 2 ;
                                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/robstephens/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/lib/node_modules/foundation-cli/node_modules/string-kit/lib/string.js:54:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

I'm reaching my wits end. Being a front-end guy, I only know enough of this to get it running when it works right. I have no idea what any of all that means.

here's the version numbers of the components

```
Node - v12.22.12
NVM - v0.39.1
NPM - v6.14.16
Yarn - v1.22.19
Bower - v1.8.14
Gulp - CLI: v2.3.0 Local: Unknown
```

Can anyone help? I really want to get a new project started!